# Why we use the StringBuilder and BufferedReader in java together?

Tags: java, android

As in BufferedReader returns the String value after `readLine()`, and `StringBuilder` is also return the same after `append(line)`. Then why we use both together ?

```
    HttpEntity he = res.getEntity();
    InputStream is= he.getContent();
    InputStreamReader ir= new InputStreamReader(is);
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(ir);
//  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line=br.readLine();
//  sb.append(line);


    JSONObject jobj= new JSONObject(line);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is used to concatenate all the line from buffered reader..
I am correcting your code

```
String line;
while((line=br.readLine())!= null){
   sb.append(line);
}
```

Even now if you don't see any difference, It means your input stream has got a single line

Comment: I already tried your above code after then  I tried my own code as I posted in my question.Here, my output is one line . So, I want to know here, single line means how many characters? I mean how many characters make one single Line in inputstream?

Comment: It can be any number of charater,A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed. as it is said in oracle documentation.For your information you to use the readLine() function as I suggested else you will get only one line if do as you did

Comment: Okay,that's fine. But the question here is if my output is one line as I got here.Then why should we take loop and why should we take StringBuilder object to append result of br.readLine() in it? When this work completed with BufferedReader object only.

Comment: How do you that is always one line?

Comment: It is very simple,If the line has not got any character like "\n" and "\r" the line is not terminated

Comment: So, here we can't predict any thing how much line we should got as reply in inputStream as you say. But my question is how can define one line or two line etc.Okay,I got from your previous comment.

Comment: Here I am using JSON to parse the data where I have not define like "\n" or  "\r". Then my output is in one line only naaa?.that's I am telling.

Comment: Yep I got your point,The while loop is used only as a good developer practice.There is no other point in it.

Answer (score 0):

They are unrelated classes.

`BufferedReader` buffers the IO operations making it more efficient and faster.

`StringBuilder` allows you to create a String in memory more efficient way (Strings do not have to be created on heap.